# Violation of clean coding principles?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a method which is something like

```
void getCalled(Predicate<Integer> predicate, List<Integer> lst){
   lst.stream().filter(predicate).forEach(...);
}
```

The thing is, for this predicate I will have exactly two choices, which are negations of each other. So the predicates are:

```
public class Helper {
   public static boolean doesExist(int x){
    return ..
   }

   public static boolean doesNotExist(int x){
     return !doesExist();
   }
}
```

Now in the caller I have confusion, which is, should I extract this

```
void caller(){
  List<Integer> lst = ...
  getCalled(lst, Helper::doesExist);
  getCalled(lst, Helper::doesNotExist);
}
```

The issue, I am not sure having extra code for `Helper::doesNotExist` is a good design practice since its just calling the negation of `doesExist`, something like:

```
void caller(){
  List<Integer> lst = ...
  getCalled(lst, Helper::doesExist);
  getCalled(lst, x -> !Helper.doesExist(x)); //Ugly
}
```

At the same time, this is the cleanest way to submit a predicate to the `getCalled` method, by having two different predicates, `doesExist` and `doesNotExist`.

Any idea

Comment: This looks like a question for Software Engineering SE. Actually, they already have a question like this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68726/should-you-create-a-boolean-function-that-does-the-opposite-of-an-existing-funct/68728

Comment: Guava `Predicates.not`.

Comment: Both are equivalent but the lambda solution is less code overall, so that's my choice

Answer (score 3):

From java 11 you can do it like this:

```
getCalled(lst, Helper::doesExist);
getCalled(lst, Predicate::not(Helper.doesExist));
```

If no - do same as [@chrylis-on-strike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis-on-strike) already said, with [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained#predicates)

Answer (score 1):

While [@Dinar Zaripov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8498513/dinar-zaripov) has given a good example, I would like to extend it with use of Static imports in java.

```
import static java.util.function.Predicate.not; // changes here

getCalled(lst, Helper::doesExist);
getCalled(lst, not(Helper::doesExist)); // changes here,
```

**This approach could be really helpful in case of passing many arguments, with possibly negation operators most of time, then you don't have to write `Predicate`, `Predicate`,.. lot of time, also, you could use method reference for the boolean function too, as `Helper::doesExist` instead of `Helper.doesExist(x)`

Hope this helps someone, somewhere in universe. :)